# Making a panorama move from side to side with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

For a photographic website and want to display panoramic photos moving side to side within a viewport. At the moment it goes left to right when the page loads but stops when it runs out of image. Instead of stopping I want it to reverse direction and go right to left, and then left to right, right to left infintum.
It is probable something very simple but I'm a complete newbie to jquery (sorry).

This is the code which I've adapted from Arnault PACHOT:

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
/* =========================================================
// jquery.panorama.js
// Author: OpenStudio (Arnault PACHOT)
// Mail: apachot@openstudio.fr
// Web: http://www.openstudio.fr
// Copyright (c) 2008 Arnault Pachot
// licence : GPL
========================================================= */

(function($) {
$.fn.panorama = function(options) {
    this.each(function(){ 
        var settings = {
            viewport_width: 669,
            speed: 20000,
            direction: 'left',
            control_display: 'auto',
            start_position: 0,
            auto_start: true,
            mode_360: false
        };
        if(options) $.extend(settings, options);

        var elemWidth = parseInt($(this).attr('width'));
        var elemHeight = parseInt($(this).attr('height'));
        var currentElement = this;
        var panoramaViewport, panoramaContainer;
        var bMouseMove = false;
        var mouseMoveStart = 0;
        var mouseMoveMarginStart = 0;

        $(this).attr('unselectable','on')
            .css('position', 'relative')
            .css('-moz-user-select','none')
            .css('-webkit-user-select','none')
            .css('margin', '0')
            .css('padding', '0')
            .css('border', 'none')
            .wrap("<div class='panorama-container'></div>");
        if (settings.mode_360) 
            $(this).clone().insertAfter(this);

        panoramaContainer = $(this).parent();
        panoramaContainer.css('height', elemHeight+'px').css('overflow', 'hidden').wrap("<div class='panorama-viewport'></div>").parent().css('width',settings.viewport_width+'px')
            .append("<div class='panorama-control'><a href='#' class='panorama-control-left'><<</a> <a href='#' class='panorama-control-pause'>x</a> <a href='#' class='panorama-control-right'>>></a> </div>");

        panoramaViewport = panoramaContainer.parent();

        panoramaViewport.mousedown(function(e){
              if (!bMouseMove) {
            bMouseMove = true;
            mouseMoveStart = e.clientX;
              }
              return false;
        }).mouseup(function(){
              bMouseMove = false;
              mouseMoveStart = 0;
              return false;
        }).mousemove(function(e){
              if (bMouseMove){
              var delta = parseInt((mouseMoveStart - e.clientX)/30);
              if ((delta>10) || (delta<10)) {
                  var newMarginLeft = parseInt(panoramaContainer.css('marginLeft')) + (delta);
                  if (settings.mode_360) {
                    if (newMarginLeft > 0) {newMarginLeft = -elemWidth;}
                    if (newMarginLeft < -elemWidth) {newMarginLeft = 0;}
                  } else {
                    if (newMarginLeft > 0) {newMarginLeft = 0;}
                    if (newMarginLeft < -elemWidth) {newMarginLeft = -elemWidth;}
                  }
                  panoramaContainer.css('marginLeft', newMarginLeft+'px');
              }

              }
        }).bind('contextmenu',function(){return false;});

        panoramaViewport.css('height', elemHeight+'px').css('overflow', 'hidden').find('a.panorama-control-left').bind('click', function() {
            $(panoramaContainer).stop();
            settings.direction = 'right';
            panorama_animate(panoramaContainer, elemWidth, settings);
            return false;
        });
        panoramaViewport.bind('click', function() {
            $(panoramaContainer).stop();
        });
        panoramaViewport.find('a.panorama-control-right').bind('click', function() {
            $(panoramaContainer).stop();
            settings.direction = 'left';
            panorama_animate(panoramaContainer, elemWidth, settings);
            return false;
        });
        panoramaViewport.find('a.panorama-control-pause').bind('click', function() {
            $(panoramaContainer).stop();
            return false;
        });

        if (settings.control_display == 'yes') {
            panoramaViewport.find('.panorama-control').show();
        } else if (settings.control_display == 'auto') {
            panoramaViewport.bind('mouseover', function(){
                $(this).find('.panorama-control').show();
                return false;
            }).bind('mouseout', function(){
                $(this).find('.panorama-control').hide();
                return false;
            });

        }

        $(this).parent().css('margin-left', '-'+settings.start_position+'px');

        if (settings.auto_start) 
            panorama_animate(panoramaContainer, elemWidth, settings);

    });
    function panorama_animate(element, elemWidth, settings) {
        currentPosition = 0-parseInt($(element).css('margin-left'));

        if (settings.direction == 'right') {

            $(element).animate({marginLeft: 0}, ((settings.speed / elemWidth) * (currentPosition)) , 'linear', function (){ 
                if (settings.mode_360) {
                    $(element).css('marginLeft', '-'+(parseInt(parseInt(elemWidth))+'px'));
                    panorama_animate(element, elemWidth, settings);
                }
            });
        } else {

            var rightlimit;
            if (settings.mode_360) 
                rightlimit = elemWidth;
            else
                rightlimit = elemWidth-settings.viewport_width;

            $(element).animate({marginLeft: -rightlimit}, ((settings.speed / rightlimit) * (rightlimit - currentPosition)), 'linear', function (){ 
                if (settings.mode_360) {
                    $(element).css('margin-left', 0); 
                    panorama_animate(element, elemWidth, settings);
                }
            });
        }


    }

};

$(document).ready(function(){
$("img.panorama").panorama();
});
in})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/pm6swLxa/

You code use css animations

HTML

`<div id="img_container" class="pano slide"></div>`

CSS

```
#img_container {
  width:400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('http://www.the-farm.net/piccies/pano2.jpg');
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: right;
  animation: back-and-forth 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes back-and-forth {
  0% {
    background-position: right;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: left;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: right;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow - that is fantastic. Almost perfect. Thanks Joshua ever so much for posting your code. Sorry to be thick but how would I add some user controls like pan left, pause/start pan right? Thanks you in advance.

Comment: If you can manage with just activating the animation on the user hover instead of left and right buttons- just add an additional style  #img_container:hover { animation: back-and-forth 5s infinite;} and remove the animation from the '#img_container' style so that it doesn't activate on page load, only on hover.